# Mount Internal drive Lubuntu

Tags: mount, hard-drive, lubuntu, filesystem

I am using Lubuntu 16.10 installed on 120 GB drive. However, I also have a secondary 1TB hard drive full of personal data and similar valuable information, yet I am unable to mount it:

```
jan@Bondy:/$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /media/diskD
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       doesg | tail or so.
```

Output of `fdisk`:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes/4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcf802303

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1             2048   32507903   32505856 15.5G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sdb2        302507904 1953521663 1921013760  916G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

I am not sure. Is something wrong with my NTFS filesystem? Might I need to format my drive again?

**EDIT:** After I split C drive into 2 partitions and installed Lubuntu again, the Lubuntu was still unable to load second drive. To the second partition I installed windows, that is able to work with second drive without any problem.

---

> **Editor's note:**
>   This post has originally contained a couple screenshots of console text. These have since been replaced with a transcription.

Comment: A note for the future. Please don't post screenshots of the console unless unavoidable. Instead, just copy-paste the console output into your question directly.

Comment: Alright, will remember that.

Comment: (hunch) I think it might help if you post the output of `gdisk /dev/sdb`. Maybe is this some kind of hybrid disk (MBR+GPT) and the MBR displayed by `fdisk` should not be relied upon.

Comment: @xhienne

`GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.1
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present


***************************************************************
Found invalid GPT and valid MBR; converting MBR to GPT format
in memory. THIS OPERATION IS POTENTIALLY DESTRUCTIVE! Exit by
typing 'q' if you don't want to convert your MBR partitions
to GPT format!
***************************************************************`

Comment: It also might be worth to mention, that when I plugged in a USB, I could find it in /media/jan/(nameOfUSB) without executing any command. And before I installed Lubuntu to hard drive, I was booting Porteus from the USB and I was unable to access the 1TB drive aswell. Even though I could even see it in file manager unlike in lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, Linux tries with the FS type it has identified and it fails.  First let's see what Linux thinks it is:

```
blkid /dev/sdb2
```

So, if it says `vfat', then try NTFS:

```
mount -t ntfs /dev/sdb2 /path/to/mount/point
```

And if it says 'ntfs', try VFAT:

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sdb2 /path/to/mount/point
```

Comment: Thank you for response. 

I did the blkid /dev/sdb2. 

And it writes nothing after executing it... :/

Comment: Strange. Try `blkid -p /dev/sdb2`. Else you can try the mount commands, it won't hurt.

Comment: No output again.
When I write just "blkid":

jan@Bondy:~$ blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="46e68169-3b5f-4b6c-a135-7db087d5742b" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="43ef7791-01"
/dev/sda5: UUID="18f0aa03-da81-429d-b698-6f01a43d36b1" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="43ef7791-05"

It does not even list the drive... Maybe I need to download some package? I'm using lightweight ubuntu.

Comment: @Bondy No, nothing to install. And the `mount` commands, what do they do? And the `fdisk` command in the original post, does it still work?

Comment: The mount says it cant be found in /etc/fstab. And it really isnt there. When I use fdisk, it is there. And when I open the Disk software, it is in there....

Comment: The output from the disk software: https://postimg.org/image/jzm7x1zwr/

Comment: @Bondy First of all, your screenshot doesn't match the output of fdisk you posted initially (the disk is mostly Free, i.e. unused, on your screenshot). Next, the mount command I posted should not search anything in fstab and thus should not output what you told me. Frankly - take no offense - you should show your system to Linux-savvy people.